# Can I Have xlwings Display Console Output?

Tags: python, vba, console, stdout, xlwings

Is it possible for xlwings to pop up a console while running a script from VBA and show stdout?

I know xlwings writes the stdout to a logfile which is useful, but I'd like to give users some updates while they are waiting for their calculation to finish.  The debugger kind of does this but seems like overkill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using UDFs, then there is a simple possibility: By default xlwings uses the `pythonw` interpreter. Just change it to `python` and the console window will pop up.

For `RunPython` you'd need to hack the source code of the addin currently, see [here](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/639). Basically search for `WindowStyle` and set it to 1 instead of 0. It should be easy to make this a config at some point.

Update:
On Windows, this is now possible via the `Show Console` setting in the add-in since version 0.20.8.

Comment: I'm not using UDFs currently, but it seems pretty easy to move over.  I'll give it a shot thanks.

Comment: @rhaskett I've updated my answer to reflect `RunPython` also.

Comment: Even better.  Appreciated.